# Android Studio Cmake: "The C compiler clang.exe is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

64 bit Windows 10. Android Studio 2.3.3.

I'm trying to use JNI to link an existing C++ project to Android Studio. I've also tried to load all of the provided NDK-JNI sample projects. Everything with JNI/Cmake is unable to Gradle Sync, failing with the same error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Alex\Desktop\android-ndk\hello-jni\app\src\main\cpp -BC:\Users\Alex\Desktop\android-ndk\hello-jni\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\armDebug\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\android-ndk\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\cmake\arm\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang}
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
The C compiler
"C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/android-ndk/hello-jni/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/armDebug/armeabi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build
Command:"C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe"
"cmTC_accda"
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_accda.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_accda
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd .  &&
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
--target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi
--gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
--sysroot=C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot
-isystem
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
-D__ANDROID_API__=23 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te
-Werror=format-security -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm64
-Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings
-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro
-Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -pie -fPIE
CMakeFiles/cmTC_f48b1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_f48b1 -lm && cd ."
The system cannot find the path specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

I have all necessary SDK tools installed. I've tried using GCC instead of clang. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a `make` binary at the same path as your `clang` binary?

Comment: Which path is that? Sorry I'm new to NDK development

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem trying to build on Windows 10 with Studio 3.0. CMake and NDK are installed.

I don't see a make.exe with clang.exe, if that makes a difference, @snoopy

Answer (score 0):

The main error message is:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Note that above some places use `/` as path separator:

```
"C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
```

and have run successfully. And this line:

```
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
```

Seems to have failed. I guess the problem is the `\`. Try find where this path is defined, maybe in the IDE options, configuration files or Makefiles, then modify it may solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Its because of clang version mismatch
check clang version you have and what minimum clang version Android Application needed!

Comment: I have no domain knowledge here. I'm just curious what makes you say that. I would think that the clang bundled with the android NDK would be compatible with whatever the rest of the NDK and anything it makes requires.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).